# JSON parsing returns null with a specific JSON file, but not the others JSON file

Tags: json, parsing

I made a class to parse a JSON file which has been validated by jsonlint. The class works perfectly fine on various .json file, but not the one I need to work on, which contains :

```
{
  "numero_de_permis": "A0001",
  "cycle": "2018-2020",
  "heures_transferees_du_cycle_precedent": 2,
  "activites": [
    {
```

The class:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LectureJson {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            try (Reader reader = new FileReader("/home/user/generated.json")) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
                System.out.println(jsonObject);

                String numeroDePermis = (String) jsonObject.get("heures");
                System.out.println(numeroDePermis);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Any idea why the returns would be

```
null
```

For any string , (exemple, "numero de permis" returns null). The class does the job for other json type file.

Thanks.

Comment: The string you have posted at the top isn't (currently) valid `JSON`.

Comment: Here is more, to give a better idea of the general file. What is the problem format wise?{
   "numero_de_permis" : "A0001",
  "cycle": "2018-2020",
  "heures_transferees_du_cycle_precedent": 2,
  "activites": [
    {
      "description": "Cours sur la déontologie",
      "categorie": "cours",
      "heures": 14,
      "date": "2019-03-20"
    } ] }